# Resetting UIViewController subviews back to the initial positions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a UIViewController that I am using a xib file for. Inside this xib file I have 6 moveable buttons. During the runtime, the user is allowed to move the buttons around the screen. But eventually the screen will need to reset back to its initial state and all the buttons should go back to their original positions predefined in the xib file.

Dismissing the controller and going back to it works fine, but how do I solve this issue when I am not dismissing the controller?

I have already tried setNeedsDisplay, that does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the center or origins for every button in the `viewDidLoad` method and then just reset them when you need to.

```
CGPoint center = myButton.center;
...
myButton.center = center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save orginal position of your buttons and when you reset screen you have to change buttons position to it's original state.

I'm not sure this work but you can try use CGAffineTransformIdentity, which should reset your button position.

```
buton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```